# Как узнать откуда идет запрос PHP

Tags: php, безопасность, include, index

И так, есть 3 файла:

> index.php,
>
> a.php ,
>
> b.php,

в файле (index.php) есть 3 функции, 2 из которих инклудят файлы (a.php) и (b.php),  их можно вызвать по ID в адресной строке. Третяя функцыя: default - тоесть если id не задан то по умолчанию инклудится файл (a.php).

Все три файла лежат в одной "родительской" папке.
По идее Вы заходите на сайт (автоматом попадаете в index.php) где есть две ссылки:

> /index.php?id=a    -инклудится  a.php ;
>
> /index.php?id=b   -инклудится b.php ;

в обоих случаях переходя по ссылкам вы остаетесь в файле index.php.
Но если в адресной строке ввести:

> localhost/a.php
> или
> localhost/b.php

Тут вы уже не будете проходить в файле index.php

Внимание вопрос:
Какую проверку (или каким способом) нужно прописать в файлах (a.php и b.php) чтобы единственным способом их просмотреть был инклуд через id, а если ктото попробует просмотреть файл на прямую  (без index.php) чтоб оба эти файла выдавали ошыбку.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В WordPress,  например, такое прямое обращение затыкают объявлением некой константы в index.php. В файле a.php проверяем, есть константа или нет. Нет - на выход.

Файлы a.php и b.php начинаем с кода

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'INDEX' ) ) {
    die( '-1' );
}
```

Comment: Byulent, указаным Вами способом я, в файле index.php проверяю какую страницу заинклудить...а или б

Comment: проблема в том как запретить запуск етих страниц (А и Б) вне файла индекс.

Comment: KAGG Design, а можно пример какойто с Вашим способом?

Comment: Добавил, как это примерно выглядит.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    //код страницы
}
```

Так?

Либо можно более конкретно

```
if($_GET['id']==имя_файла_без_расширения) {
    //код страницы
}
```

Это должно быть в `a.php` и `b.php`

Comment: Вадим, вам же написали в первом ответе адекватный вариант с константой, его и пользуйте. Или вы не разобрались с ним?

Answer (score 0):

Можно на уровне сервера запретить доступ к файлам к которым доступа быть не должно

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<Files /index.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

Ну или писать роуты для доступа к определенным контроллерам.

Comment: evgv, чепез htaccess не то...

Comment: проблему решает но нужно именно средствами php, именно через скрипт